# How to get npm tests output with colors in tfs build log console

Tags: node.js, tfs, npm, karma-runner, tfsbuild

I have a tfs 2017 build which is running npm tests.
when executing the build all of the npm tests output is not colourized but they are colurized when I execute these test in command line without the build.

How can I get these colours written with karma to be the same on the build log console?

Answer (score 0):

See the "color" in npm config:

- https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#color

If you set it to "always" then it will always output in color. The default is to output in color only if directly connected to a tty.

But keep in mind that the test runner that `npm test` starts may also need to be configured accordingly.

If you're using karma-runner then see this:

- http://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

and search for "color" config option.

If nothing helps then you may be able to trick the program that it's being connected to a real tty with tools like script:

- http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html

Comment: hey, thanks for the answers. both config npm and karma are set with colors and it does not work. the script tool is only available for linux as I understood. any other way to make text colors in the build console?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The build log doesn't capture color.